# How to efficiently backup multiple email accounts in Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, backup, microsoft-outlook-2013

Severally exporting each .pst file is too inefficient, for multiple Outlook email accounts. 
So how can I export all .pst files simultaneously and instantly?

Comment: What have you researched or attempted so far?

Answer (score -1):

1. Open Registry.
2. Navigate to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\Profiles`
3. Right-click on **Profiles** and **Export** the entire **Profiles** branch to a file.
4. Backup your PST files.

Re-install Office 2013, then...

1. Open Outlook. This will re-create the registry keys and PSTs.
2. Close Outlook.
3. Find the **NEW** PST and delete it.
4. Re-Open Outlook, it will complain about the PST file being missing, so point it back to your original PST file that you backed up.
5. Close and Re-Open outlook to ensure it is using your old PST file, then close it again.
6. Import the registry file you exported in the first section.
7. Open Outlook, click Send/Receive and re-input all your passwords and click the save (if you wish for them to be saved).

Comment: What?  Export the profiles? from regedit?  To backup the files, have a backup?  I don’t understand the second part of the answer at all.  How do you “point [Outlook] back to your original pst file”?

Comment: @Scott, while a little more effort could make the answer clearer, reading the entire question gives you all the context you need. "Profiles" were exported in the first section, and they are imported in the second section. Section 1 step 5 is unnecessary and just refers to completing Section 1 step 4.

Comment: I’m sorry — maybe I’m just too dense, but I have read the entire question, and I don’t see it.  The question seems to be about making periodic backups (of all the users’ mailboxes) on an Outlook system.  The answer seems to be oriented toward a migration from one version of Outlook to another.  The question asks about exporting `.pst` files — that sounds like an Outlook operation (exporting users’ mailboxes to `.pst` files), and the answer is describing a RegEdit operation.  I guess one of us just doesn’t understand the question (and it might be me, but AFAICT, you haven’t clarified it).

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.